# Restricting remote branch remove access in GIT

Tags: git

I am new to GIT.

When user is having read-write access to the remote repository, he can delete the remote branches as well using the command: git push origin :.

Is there any way to restrict access so users are not allowed to remove remote branches?

after google, I got the URL below: Cannot delete remote branch in git

I tried the following command for applying the hook, but it is failing: git --git-dir G:/LocalGIT_Repo/SCM_Branches/.gitconfig --bool hooks.allowdeletebranch false

Can anyone please help me in this? Thanks in advance

Comment: @Hasturkun, When i run the command, it throws me the below error.
**Unknown option: --bool**

Answer (score 0):

The general answer to "how do I impose access restrictions on users pushing to my git server" is "use [gitolite](http://git-scm.com/book/ch4-8.html)" as obtained from [gitolite on github](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite).

Gitolite is written in Perl, and I <s>hate</s> have a strong distaste for :-) Perl, so a short while ago, for fun, I wrote a shell script version of a pre-receive hook that has some access restriction controls.  It's not well tested at all but it's available [here](http://web.torek.net/torek/git/pre-receive.sh.txt).

Comment: ,Thanks.. But am using GIT in windows OS. I tried using your script.. But it didn't worked.. :(

Comment: I "don't do Windows", as the saying goes, but it might be workable with cygwin.  There are instructions for setting up gitolite on windows at http://therightstuff.de/CommentView,guid,b969ea4d-8d2c-42af-9806-de3631f4df68.aspx (I have no idea if or how well this works).